# Typer error issue with reactjs, Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone I need some help with react. I am doing an assignment to make a basic movie review database. Everytime I click on a movie to get details the right information will load for a few seconds and then I get this error.

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4COAk.png)

Here is my code for moviedetails.js

```
class MovieDetail extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    if (this.props.selectedMovie == null) {
        dispatch(fetchMovie(this.props.title));
    }
}

render() {
    const DetailInfo = () => {
        if (!this.props.selectedMovie) {
            return <div>Loading....</div>
        }

        return (
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>Movie Detail</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Image className="image" src={this.props.selectedMovie.ImageURL} thumbnail />
                </Card.Body>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem>{this.props.selectedMovie.title}</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>

                        {this.props.selectedMovie.actors.map((actor, i) =>
                            <p key={i}>
                                <b>{actor.actorName}</b> {actor.characterName}
                            </p>)}
                    </ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem><h4><BsStarFill/> {this.props.selectedMovie.averageRating}</h4></ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
                <Card.Body>
                    {this.props.selectedMovie.Reviews.map((review, i) =>
                        <p key={i}>
                            <b>{review.name}</b>&nbsp; {review.review}
                            &nbsp;  <BsStarFill /> {review.rating}
                        </p>
                    )}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    }

    return (
        <DetailInfo />
    )
}
}

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            selectedMovie: state.movie.selectedMovie
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MovieDetail)
```

;

Any help or hints is greatly appreciated I've tried for so many hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that props.selectedMovie.actors is undefined. Try logging props.selectedMovie.actors to confirm this. My guess is that props.selectedMovie too is undefined, meaning that prop isn't being passed to MovieDetail. Either way, something is off with the props you are passing, so check MovieDetail's parent component and ensure that the right props are being passed there. If that doesn't work, please provide a running codesandbox of the concerned piece of your project, so that we can take a look at the problem in better detail.

Answer (score 0):

The Redux is taking time to fetch data at that time data will be undefined easy way to fix it is using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

replace

```
this.props.selectedMovie.actors.map  to  this.props?.selectedMovie?.actors?.map
```

and this also

```
this.props.selectedMovie.Reviews.map to this.props?.selectedMovie?.Reviews?.map
```

Final Code

```
class MovieDetail extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    if (this.props.selectedMovie == null) {
        dispatch(fetchMovie(this.props.title));
    }
}

render() {
    const DetailInfo = () => {
        if (!this.props.selectedMovie) {
            return <div>Loading....</div>
        }

        return (
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>Movie Detail</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Image className="image" src={this.props.selectedMovie?.ImageURL} thumbnail />
                </Card.Body>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem>{this.props.selectedMovie?.title}</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>

                        {this.props?.selectedMovie?.actors?.map((actor, i) =>
                            <p key={i}>
                                <b>{actor.actorName}</b> {actor.characterName}
                            </p>)}
                    </ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem><h4><BsStarFill/> {this.props.selectedMovie.averageRating}</h4></ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
                <Card.Body>
                    {this.props.selectedMovie?.Reviews?.map((review, i) =>
                        <p key={i}>
                            <b>{review.name}</b>&nbsp; {review.review}
                            &nbsp;  <BsStarFill /> {review.rating}
                        </p>
                    )}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    }

    return (
        <DetailInfo />
    )
}
}

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            selectedMovie: state.movie.selectedMovie
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MovieDetail)

``
```

Answer (score 0):

The fetch operation is an asynchronous call so it may take time so add a check if its not undefined. Try doing this.

```
{this.props.selectedMovie.actors && this.props.selectedMovie.actors.map((actor, i) => {
   ...
   }
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.